# Design linear equation system to solve equation with three variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How to solve an equation with three variables given just one equation, for example:

$$12x+5y+z=35$$

I think that I need to create a linear equation system $3\times3$ and then use sustitution, but I don't know how to design this system.

Comment: Maybe u could choose a better title... (this is too general, don't u agree?)

Comment: Totally, but I don't know how to express my question, any suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion is: "Solving the equation $12x+5y+z=35$" or something having $12x+5y+z=35$ (to be more specific)

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve this equation in "normal" sense (meaning that you can't get solutions of form such as x = 1, y = 2, z = 3).

The only thing that you can do is express each variable in terms of other two. For example z = 35 - 12x - 5y and the same for x and y.

System of equations is not something that you can "create". You must have three equations right at the start if you want to solve equation with three variables in "normal" sense.

Could you give some more info about problem that this equation relies to? Maybe you misinterpreted something...

Comment: Thank you for answer. This equation is present in the documentation of a software, design by and old co-worker. The result of this equation is used to generate a code. In database, I have this code but I need to find out which values were used to generated, I mean, what are the values for x, y and z in each code.

Comment: Well as I said. You can't solve this equation. But maybe you can gues some solutions (there are in fact many solutions). For example x = 0, y = 0, z = 35 and than try them in you software. Smarter way would actually be to try many solutions and try to figure which is the closest to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You would set it up like this then do row-reduction:

$\left[\begin{align}
12 && 5 && 1 && 35\\
0  && 1 && 0 &&  s\\
0 && 0 && 1 && t
\end{align}\right]$

If using equations:

\begin{eqnarray}
12x+5y+z&=&35\\
y\phantom{+zz}&=&s\\
z&=&t
\end{eqnarray}

then use back substitution.